# Textarea on focus

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the code below to try and get the value to show before clicking.  I want the value "reply here" to show in the texarea and when someone clicks it should go away letting them type their reponse.  I am using the code below but it doesn't show the value until one click in the box.  How can i tweak it?

```
    onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" 
    onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Reply          
    here':this.value;" value="Reply here"
```

Comment: please make clear which coding language you are talking about

Comment: @dnl i got it now.  all i have to do is put the default value in between the <textarea>value here</textarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textarea's dont take the "value" attribute, to set a default value of a textarea use the following:

```
<textarea>reply here</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for a different answer, but thought I could shine some light on what's available with HTML5. All you need to do is do the following:

```
<textarea placeholder="Reply here"></textarea>
```

However, I'm sure it doesn't work with much older browsers, but here's a link to get backward compatibility: [how to use HTML5 placeholder attribute with backward-compatibility in mind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561235/how-to-use-html5-placeholder-attribute-with-backward-compatibility-in-mind)