# jquery: How to set a few onmouse listeners

Tags: jquery

Not sure what i am doing wrong but  `alert(titleTxt)`; shows always  `other_location`. I need add two `onmouse` listeners but seems it is always attached to the last element.

```
function ghostText(name){
    obj = $("input[name='"+name+"']");
    titleTxt = obj.val();
    obj.css('color', '#cccccc');
    obj.mouseover(function() {
        if(obj.val() == titleTxt){
            obj.val(""); 
            obj.css('color', '#333333');
        }
        alert(titleTxt);
    });
    obj.mouseout(function() {
        if(obj.val() == ''){
            obj.val(titleTxt); 
            obj.css('color', '#cccccc');
        }
    });
}

ghostText('keyword');
ghostText('other_location');
```

Comment: Wouldn't simply adding `placeholder` attribute do what you need?

Comment: `placeholder` attribute is an HTML5 feature so, its not backward compatible.

Comment: @rcdmk unless you are building an intranet app specifically targeted for IE6, that is hardly an issue.

Comment: So you can look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561235/how-to-use-html5-placeholder-attribute-with-backward-compatibility-in-mind

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, but current versions of IE, FF and Chrome support placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

Your variables `titleText` and `obj` are implicit global variables.  You need to put `var` in front of them so they are local variables and can have different values for each invocation of the `ghostText()` function.

Your alert is always showing the value of the last call to `ghostText()` because `titleText` is a global variable who's value gets changed every time `ghostText()` is called.  It should look like this:

```
function ghostText(name){
    var obj = $("input[name='"+name+"']");
    var titleTxt = obj.val();
    obj.css('color', '#cccccc');
    obj.mouseover(function() {
        if(obj.val() == titleTxt){
            obj.val(""); 
            obj.css('color', '#333333');
        }
        alert(titleTxt);
    });
    obj.mouseout(function() {
        if(obj.val() == ''){
            obj.val(titleTxt); 
            obj.css('color', '#cccccc');
        }
    });
}

ghostText('keyword');
ghostText('other_location');
```

Though the above code seems fine, you could use `.hover()` and use method chaining to take advantage of jQuery a little more:

```
function ghostText(name){
    var obj = $("input[name='"+name+"']").css('color', '#cccccc');
    var titleTxt = obj.val();
    obj.hover(function() {
        if(obj.val() == titleTxt){
            obj.val("").css('color', '#333333'); 
    }, function() {
        if(obj.val() == ''){
            obj.val(titleTxt).css('color', '#cccccc');
        }
    });
}

ghostText('keyword');
ghostText('other_location');
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, you could bind the mouseover and mouseout events with the following example:

**Edit:** Updated JavaScript for a better "ghosttext"

#### HTML

```
<input name="keyword" value="foo"/>
<input name="other_location" value="bar"/>
```

#### CSS

```
input {
    color:#cccccc;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('input[name="keyword"], input[name="other_location"]').on('mouseover', function() {
    if (this.defaultValue == this.value) {
        $(this).css('color', '#333333');
    }
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).css('color', '#cccccc');

    if (this.value == '') {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    } else if (this.defaultValue != this.value) {
        $(this).css('color', '#333333');
    }
}).on('click', function() {
    if (this.defaultValue == this.value) {
        this.value = '';
    }
});
```

as demonstrated in [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xkvn8/1/). Note this example requires jQuery 1.7 or above since I have used the newer event binding method [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) however it is perfectly possible using the older [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`.mouseout()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) methods.

Comment: This doesn't answer the real problem. his problem is to simulate the `placeholder` HTML5 attribute.

Comment: @rcdmk Actually that was my guess. OP does not state that. Really, it is totally unclear what OP is trying to do, but this answer seem to follow given question fairly closely.

Comment: @rcdmk I agree that the `placeholder` is _probably_ what the OP was after. Updated answer with a better solution. I'm not going to claim it's bug free though :-)

Comment: If this answer is the solution could you please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it so that other users will be able to see more clearly which answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `titleText` *is a global property* and changes are "shared".

The code in the post is therefor essentially doing:

```
// ghostText('keyword')
window.titleTxt = obj.val()       // 'keyword'
// ghostText('other_location')
window.titleTxt = obj.val()       // 'other_location'
// later in a callback
alert(window.titleTxt)            // 'other_location'
```

(Note that there is only *one* property named `window.titleTxt`.)

Instead, use a *local variable*:

```
var titleTxt = obj.val()
```

The `var` keyword, in function-scope, annotates that `titleTxt` is a local variable: this variable will subsequently be closed over in the callbacks due to the lexical scope. See [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript). (Note that each function invocation has it's *own* `titleTxt` variable in this scenario.)

Happy coding.